# In Grid record search using ajax? and How can set Reset button for reset data of custom form?

Tags: magento-1.7

I created grid and custom form admin side. when i press on row it will open the form and there is one button for reset i click on it, it won't work. i tried to set action in controller and other thing but it not work.

and other problem is that in grid when i search data from particular column it reset whole page and display answer but i want to get output through ajax so, that page will not refresh.
How can i set ajax code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Regarding the Ajax grids

You need to:

*Update thanks to the comment of Richard Parnaby-King:*
I forgot to mention this: set the use_ajax property of the grid block to true:

```
$this->setUseAjax(true)
```

This can be done in the `_construct()` method.

Then implement the method `getGridUrl()` on your grid block to return the Ajax request URL

```
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current' => true));
}
```

Then you need to create the controller action method to process the Ajax request. It's simple, it only needs to instantiate and render the grid block. You can do that either via `$this->loadLayout(false)->renderLayout()` and add the grid block via layout XML, or instantiate and render it using PHP:

```
$this->getResponse()->setBody(
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('my_module/adminhtml_my_grid')->toHtml()
)
```

Thats all. To summarize, there are three steps:

1. Implement the `getGridUrl()` method
2. Implement the controller grid url action
3. Render (only) the grid block

### Regarding the Reset Button

The reset button should trigger a page reload via the JavaScript `setLocation(window.location.href)`.

It's added in the constructor of the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container`.

```
$this->_addButton('reset', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Reset'),
    'onclick'   => 'setLocation(window.location.href)',
), -1);
```

If it doesn't work, it's probably because some other customization of yours breaks JavaScript execution.
To simply get rid of the button you could place a `$this->removeButton('reset')` into the `_prepareLayout()` method of your form container.

Comment: I am also interested in making my grids ajax, but my code already has the above in it.

Comment: Whoo - got the ajax working. In the grid block constructor, add `$this->setUseAjax(true);`.

Comment: ok, Thanks Vinai. Can you help me for reset button?

Comment: Updated the answer to address the reset button issue, too.

Comment: it shows invalid method.
`a:5:{i:0;s:107:"Invalid method Xyz_Example_Block_Adminhtml_Data_Detail_Grid::removeButton(Array
(
    [0] => reset
)`

Comment: Sorry, you need to add the removeButton call to the form container block, not the grid block.

Comment: same error message

Comment: Your container must extend from ```Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container```, which in turn extends from ```Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container```, which implements ```public function removeButton($id)```. Check your code again.